# Java 1.8 applet security exception in IE11, can I srill self sign jars these days?

Tags: java, security, applet

I've been asked to modify an applet I wrote when I was still a young man! I've actually replaced it with an application but for various reasons this client wants the applet for now. I last touched this code ten years ago. My client is using Java 1.6 but wants this updated to 1.8.

I'm testing on IE11, 1.8.x, Windows 10 all 64 bit. My IE11 will run the java.com version verify applet so Java seems to be OK.

When I run it under appletviewer I get a security exception at a system.getProperty call. But I read applet viewer is no longer capable of working with signed applets?

Under IE11 when I open the local webpage (on my hard drive, not webserver) I get an "allow blocked content" dialog then nothing at all - no Java console (it starts OK on the java.com verify page).

I'm using a self signed security key, is this still allowed?

I know the whole signing / manifest thing changed under 1.7 but my memory is failing me. Perhaps something there is the problem.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Did you try to import the public key of your self-sign certificate and import it to IE via the Internet Options dialog?

Comment: I think I need an X.509 certificate for that, am I right in thinking that's not what keytool makes? In the old version I think the client has to accept our certificate in a dialog before the app starts. Please forgive my vagueness, long day. Tried to import it and it says it's an unknown format.

Comment: I guess that System.getProperty meet a particular security browser setting, that can me modified to allow this type of getting.

Comment: It's just a format issue, see [this](https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/627.html) for example

Comment: *"..can I srill self sign jars these days?"* Ha ha ha.. sure you can, but no recent JRE will launch it. The laughing was because applets themselves are completely dead. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: I know applets are dead, that's why the replacement is an application. But this one clients wants to keep the applet for now.